# can I ftp-upload a file from my web page?

Tags: file-upload, ftp

Is there a client or plugin that allows me to put a frame/upload field on my web site that will let my users upload files to my ftp server without an ftp client software of their own? Preferrably one where I can pre-configure the ftp username/password automatically (from data I have stored about the logged-in user)?

In a digital signage solution we let users upload video files to their account, and currently have the solution of uploading via ftp (the file is then renamed and moved, users can NOT use this feature to share video files. Furthermore it is solely about videos they themselves made, no license breakage. Just as a disclaimer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try third-party software like uploadify, or a service like http://www.net2ftp.com/ which can be somewhat integrated with php.